# Multiple pins drooping at same point when using MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have written code to search something which returns the lat and long and accordingly I am dropping pins at corresponding location. A lot of times i can see multiple pins dropping at the same location.(10-15 pins dropping at same position instead of once)

This happens very randomly. What could be the problem?

Thanks,
Himanshu

Comment: did you check all lat and lng? they are not same?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of the method where you drop the pins?

Answer (score 2):

Go and update your code. This should fix the issue.

Comment: lol.  just went through this again. Explanation: I was the other developer in the project OP was working. The error was because of some logical error in the code.